# Write a program in Java though array and pop up element after multiplication

Tags: java

```
Inputs ={6,7,8,9,10}
Outputs ={42,56,72,90}
```

Multiplication needs to be done

```
// arr[ ] = {6*7,7*8,8*9,9*10}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information,  see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Solution :

class Adarsh
{
static void modify(int arr[ ], int n )
{ if (n<=1)
return;
int previous = arr[0];
arr[0]= arr[0]* arr[1];
for (int=1;I<n-1;I++)
int current = arr[i];
arr[¡]=previous * arr[¡+1];
previous = arr;
arr[n-1] = previous × arr [n-1];

public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
int arr[ ]= {6,7,8,9,10}
int n = arr.length;
modify(arr, n );
for ( ¡=0; ¡< n; ¡++)
System.out.println(arr[¡] + " " );
}
}

Answer (score 1):

for i--> input.length
     Outputs[i] = input[i]*input[i+1]